# Send additional attribute to remote portlet consuming with wsrp in liferay

Tags: liferay, wsrp

When consuming a remote portlet with wsrp, it is possible to send additional attributes and have access to them in the remote portlet? When setting a custom attribute to the current request object in liferay this attribute isn't accessible in the remote portlet, because it's a totally different session. Is there any best practice to solve this? Or isn't this a use case when consuming remote portlets with wsrp?

Comment: Which portlet's ws are you consuming? You can send parameters are per your requirement if your service method accepts.

Comment: What do you mean with "which portlet ws"? It's a standard portlet deployed in a remote liferay tomcat.

Comment: And what do you mean with "method accepts"? How can I change the portlet to accept methods?

Comment: I mean to say, you can modify your ws method to accept additional parameter.

Comment: So I need to change the ws soap call and this only possible by changing the wsrp internal code. Isn't there any easier solution? I guess it's a common use case to send additional parameters to a remote portlet ...